# Bibdesk texpreview fail after adding preamble

Tags: bibtex, mac, bibdesk

BibDesk doesn't allow me to Tex preview my citations after I added the following line to the preamble of my template file:

```
@preamble{"\newcommand{\SortNoop}[1]{}"}
```

(this is the only preamble I have). When I remove this line, TeX preview works again. How do I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at the log file of the failed preview you it should tell you what the source of the error is.

[image]

Depending on how you are producing the preview it may be that the command you've put in the preamble is already defined. I'm using `natbib` and `apalike` to preview, and I got the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Command \SortNoop already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.

See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.1 ...{\SortNoop}[1]{}\newcommand{\SortNoop}[1]{}
```

If you are sure you want this to be the definition of `\SortNoop`, then you should use `\renewcommand` instead of `\newcommand` in the `@preamble` definition.

If you get another error, then edit your question with the output of that error if this doesn't answer your question.